# Big O as a measure of time complexity

Tags: notation, asymptotics, definition, computational-complexity

I don't fully understand, why we use the big O to measure the time complexity of an algorithm. For example, suppose that the time complexity is $O(n!)$. Usually, we think that this is really bad. But wouldn't we write $ e^{-n} = O(n!) $ as well, which would mean that the time complexity decreases (even exponentially)!

That is, because for every $x \ge 0$, we have $$ e^{-n} \le n! , $$
so we write $e^{-n} = O(n!)$.

Comment: It is not exact time complexity, but rather "upper bound" for it. If you would like consider "tight complexity", then it's more appropriate big-$\Theta$.

Comment: Often when programmers say an algorithm takes $O(f(n))$ time, they can actually prove the worst-case performance is in $O(f(n))\setminus o(f(n))$. It would be pointless to say "bubble sort is $O(n^3)$" or infinitely many other options when it's $o(n^3)$. See also @zkutch's suggestion, [Big Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) notation.